# Azure Data Factory nested dynamic content - value holds 'dynamic content string'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to pass a 'dynamic content expression' as dynamic content into a pipeline task but it fails & looking at the input it's passing the string literal instead of evaluating the expression

Is there a way to tell ADF to evaluate the passed in value?

I have a lookup task which returns the following data set which goes into a foreach loop

| Type | Object | HttpBody |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person | 111 | Content=@{items().Type}&LookupId=@{items().Object}&format=json |
| Locations |  | Content=@{items().Type}&format=json |

The foreach loop has a data copy with a HTTP api as the source
I'm passing in @item().HttpBody as the Body dynamic content but it fails because it tries to run the http call with
"body": "Content=@{items().Type}&LookupId=@{items().Object}&format=json"
instead of
"body": "Content=Person&LookupId=111&format=json"

I've tried wrapping random things in () and {} but it doesn't seem to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above scenario and **AFAIK**, Currently in ADF, nested dynamic content might not be possible. It will take that only as a string not as a dynamic content.

The workaround for this case is **building that url first using normal dynamic content and pass it to HTTP API inside For loop**.

Here, this is my source data and I have given this to lookup activity and later using it in the ForEach activity.

[image]

Using the `@item().HttpBody` values, I have replaced the strings `"@{item().Type}"` and `"@{item().Object}"` with dynamic content `item().Type` and `item().Object` i.e, values in that particular iteration.

Use the below dynamic content to build the url and pass its value to the HTTP API after set variable activity inside the same For loop.

```
@replace(replace(item().HttpBody,'@{item().Type}',coalesce(item().Type,'')),'@{item().Object}',coalesce(item().Object,''))
```

[image]

**URLs in each iteration:**

[image]

[image]

One limitation of this approach is, if your URL is involving with lot of columns then you need to use replace for all of it.

Comment: ugh - I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to string manipulation.  
There's another gotcha you haven't mentioned; the variable is at the pipeline scope, not the foreach loop scope. It can only be run sequentially. Parallel executions will overwrite variable1

Comment: In dataflow, there is an expression function which might be useful in this case. But in ADF, AFAIK, there is not any function like that. You can raise a feature reuqest for that if you want.